# Why does the "N choose k" method, scipy.misc.comb(n,k) differ so much between Python2.x and Python3.x?

Tags: python, scipy

This came up as an issue for me in a Project Euler solution to Problem (spoiler):

> [15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15)

Python2.7.10 / 0.13.0b1: `scipy.misc.comb(40,20) -> array(137846528819.9994)`

Python3.5.0 / scipy 0.16.0: `scipy.misc.comb(40,20) -> 137846528820.00006`

Frustratingly, I learned I had to call the `round()` function on the result, rather than directly cast to an `int()` or use `math.floor()`/`math.ceil()` for Python 2 / 3 consistency.

What is causing this discrepancy between the two Python / SciPy versions?

Is there any reason the SciPy developers did not just call `round()` on the returned result within `scipy.misc.comb()` in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the same integer (long) value if you use `exact=True` parameter.

> ```
> exact : bool, optional
>     If `exact` is False, then floating point precision is used, otherwise
>     exact long integer is computed.
> ```

I don't have enough versions installed, but I suspect the floating point difference has to do with a change in the code between versions 13 and 14.  13 returns the `array()`, result, 14 (and later) returns a float (numpy.float64).

I'd suggest looking at the Python code itself to see what's different.  In the `exact` case they look the same, but the floating case is quite different.

v 13:

```
    from scipy import special
    k,N = asarray(k), asarray(N)
    lgam = special.gammaln
    cond = (k <= N) & (N >= 0) & (k >= 0)
    sv = special.errprint(0)
    vals = exp(lgam(N+1) - lgam(N-k+1) - lgam(k+1))
    sv = special.errprint(sv)
    return where(cond, vals, 0.0)
```

v 14

```
    k,N = asarray(k), asarray(N)
    cond = (k <= N) & (N >= 0) & (k >= 0)
    vals = binom(N, k)
    if isinstance(vals, np.ndarray):
        vals[~cond] = 0
    elif not cond:
        vals = np.float64(0)
    return vals
```

The `exact` code is iterative, and may be slower (when N,k are in the 100s):

```
    val = 1
    for j in xrange(min(k, N-k)):
        val = (val*(N-j))//(j+1)
```